How does the master key disrupt card work in Vaults?
In Vaults, there is a card with the following wording:

Place this key on any crew, they may crack any vault this turn

Does this mean that I can use someone else's crew to crack open a vault for myself?

did you try to find the answer in the rules? If so, can you cite the part in the rules that talks about the subject?  Link to the rules:
https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/105724/rulebook-version-14

I did. It does not anywhere mention anything about who the effect applies to.

No.
If you intend read Master Key to allow that, that would also mean that any player could use any other player's crew on any crack phase, since the rules use language similar to the text you quote for Master Key -- that is, they always reference "a crew" and never "one of your crews" when talking about cracking, which is clearly not the way the game works.
But also note that if you allow it, the "someone else" player is the one who would get the vault, not you, which makes the question of trying that alternate reading moot.
Rules:

After cracking, the vault becomes the property of the player that cracked it.


"After cracking, the vault becomes the property of the player that cracked it.", yes so I cracked it with someone else's crew, so it should become mine, no?

@kersarling, No, not by the rulebook. See also the second (the main) paragraph if you want to pursue that logic. The crew cracks the vault; the crew gets the spoils.
